# C++ = assigning coordinate in array

Tags: c++

so i got some trouble. basically i just want to assign coordinate inputed by player to an array.

here is the code:

```
void Board::playerInput(int inputX, int inputY, char symbol)
{
    _board[inputX][inputY] = symbol;
}
```

and here is code where player assign the coordinate:

```
void manager::askMove()
{
    if (_turn == _player1._playerName){ 
        cout << "insert your x coordinate, " << _player1._playerName << ": ";
        _player1.inputX();
        cout << "insert your y coordinate, " << _player1._playerName << ": ";
        _player1.inputY();
        _board.playerInput(_player1.inputX, _player1.inputY, _player1._playerSymbol);
        _turn = _player2._playerName;
    }
    else {
        cout << "insert your x coordinate, " << _player2._playerName << ": ";
        _player2.inputX();
        cout << "insert your y coordinate, " << _player2._playerName << ": ";
        _player2.inputY();
        _board.playerInput(_player2.inputX, _player2.inputY, _player2._playerSymbol);
        _turn = _player1._playerName;
    }
}
```

and after i build the code. i got these errors:

```
Error   2   error C3867: 'Player::inputX': function call missing argument list; use '&Player::inputX' to create a pointer to member c:\users\rlngstrdrgntr\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\project1\project1\manager.cpp  52  1   Project1
Error   3   error C3867: 'Player::inputY': function call missing argument list; use '&Player::inputY' to create a pointer to member c:\users\rlngstrdrgntr\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\project1\project1\manager.cpp  52  1   Project1
Error   4   error C3867: 'Player::inputX': function call missing argument list; use '&Player::inputX' to create a pointer to member c:\users\rlngstrdrgntr\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\project1\project1\manager.cpp  60  1   Project1
Error   5   error C3867: 'Player::inputY': function call missing argument list; use '&Player::inputY' to create a pointer to member c:\users\rlngstrdrgntr\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\project1\project1\manager.cpp  60  1   Project1
```

i'm not really familiar with these pointers. and i've tried giving & mark like suggested on error report but it just gives me another error.
maybe you guys can help me. thank you.

edit:

here is inputX decalration

```
void Player::inputX()
{
    cin >> _playerInputX;
}

void Player::inputY()
{
    cin >> _playerInputY;
}
```

Comment: A member function isn't an `int`.

Comment: Show the declaration of `Player::inputX` please.

Comment: so what should i use chris??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
_player2.inputY();
_board.playerInput(_player2.inputX, _player2.inputY, _player2._playerSymbol);
```

It looks like your `Player` class offers the methods `inputX()` and `inputY()`, which you are calling in the first line of this snippet. In the second line, you are writing `_player2.inputY`, like it was a member variable. That's why the compiler complains: It looks like it should be a function call, but the argument list (the `()`) is missing.

After reading your edit, it guess that is what you really want to do:

```
_board.playerInput(_player2.playerInputX, _player2.playerInputY, _player2._playerSymbol);
```

Comment: oh my god.. this... i really feel so stupid now. i assign a method instead of variable. oh my god. thank you so much. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your code.

First something like

```
class MyClass
{

    public:
        int var;
        void var() { ... }
};
```

won't compile.
Your methods can not have the same name as a member variable.
So in your case you could do

```
class Player
{
        int m_x;
        int m_y;
        ...
    public:
        ...
        int x() const { return m_x; }
        int y() const { return m_y; }
        void inputX();
        void inputY()
};
```

Secondly you appear to use global variables whose name starts with an underline.
These names are [reserved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) for compiler implementers!

Moreover `manager::askMove` contains a lot of duplicated code and the distribution of the overall functionality appears odd to me.

Comment: yes i use underline for public variable but i don't know if it's global. it's just before, i used it as private variable and it seems i got confused when i want to access the variable so i just public it. and that askMove is just asking players what coordinate they want to assign. i don't know yet about good distribution in code. so yeah basically i just implement what i know now